# Will there be a golden badge for continuously visiting this website for 365 days?

Tags: support

I have come to this decision that reputation and badges should be the least thing I care about. But still I cannot help wondering:

1. Will there be a golden badge for continuously visiting this website
   for 365 days?
2. If not, will the fanatic badge be awarded more than once? If yes, is it two fanatics for continuously visiting 200 days, or two fanatics for two "continuous visiting 100 days" with some day(s) non-visit between?

Thanks for reading these dumb questions!

Comment: I can tell you from experience, unfortunately, that visiting for 200 consecutive days does not result in two Fanatic badges.

Comment: I know that, because I am now close to 365!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can tell that visiting the site everyday for 570 days, and most of them at least once every few hours... does not result in a badge. After a full year, however, you get a [Yearling badge](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/13/yearling) if you have gained at least 200 reputation in that year.

Unlike the Yearling badge which is given for every year you have gained 200 reputation in, the Fanatic badge is not awarded several times.

Comment: That is discouraging. I think I should have visited the site less frequently.

Comment: Why? It's fun! :-)

Comment: My eyesight drops ... :-(

Comment: You should exercise your eyes more often. Gaze into the distance and slowly focus and unfocus your eyes. Try to focus and look at different parts of the view while moving your pupils as little as possible. Close your eyes and make $\infty$ motions with your pupils (you can keep your eyes open, but it can cause nausea).

Comment: Also you should probably never put the internet in a higher priority than your health!

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Also, I hate to be the one to tell you this... but these **were** the droids you were looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by droids? I am not able to make sense out of your comment by replacing droids with robots or lifeless persons.

Comment: @Tim It's a reference to the film *Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila One does not simply make a reference to Star Wars in meta.SE

Comment: @PeterT.off How has this meme become so popular??

Comment: @Benjamin: What meme?

Comment: @AsafKaragila http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/one-does-not-simply-walk-into-mordor

Comment: @BenjaminLim memebase, 9gag, among others, most probably.